# I need your help with 'subjective pronoun'

Tags: grammar

Please read the following sentence!

'I'm going to present to some people we hope will become investors'.

I think the sentence should be changed into one below.
'I'm going to present to some people [who] we hope will become investors'.
I don't know why the sentence is missing 'who' (subjective relative)

Answer (score 0):

Independent clause: "I'm going to present to some people"

Dependent clause: "we hope will become investors."

To make the dependent clause independent we add a pronoun: "we hope they will become investors."

In the complete sentence, "they" is a redundant (not necessary) pronoun because the subject of the clauses doesn't change, i.e. "investors" = "they"

Therefore the relative pronoun "who", which functions as "they" is also redundant & may be omitted.

I hope this helps! :)